# Delegate draw function to stage and customize inside actors

Tags: libgdx

I have a question about stages and actors in libgdx. I'd like to delegate the draw function to stage, in order to use actions, but I need to customize these actors. Are there any way to extend an actor, assign him an Image or Texture, and not implement the draw method? Is mandatory implement the draw method or is there a way to delegate this to the stage?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for `Image`. `Image` is a subclass of `Actor` which allready implements a `draw`-method itself. You can simply give its constructor a `Drawable` and it will `draw` it at the right position with the right size, scale, rotation...
So what you want is to extend `Image`.

The `stage` is not responsible for the `draw`ing, it is just the "manager", which tells the `Actor`s to `update` and `draw` themself. As much as i know it actually calls `draw` only for those `Actor`s, which are inside the `camera`, as others are not visible and so they don't have to be drawn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need an Actor. I find the solution, we need to draw in getX() and getY() position, the actions take the rest of the job!  `code`public class TestActor extends Actor {

 // constructor
 public TestActor(){

 }
 
 // updates
 public void act(float delta){
  super.act(delta);
 }
 
 // draw
 public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
  
  batch.draw(Assets.atlas.findRegion("logo_cj"), getX(), getY());
 }
}

Comment: @HariSeldon `Image` is an `Actor`. The only difference is, that it allready takes care about the drawing at `getX()` and `getY()`.